# No such element: Unable to locate element with ID in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am getting the following error when using Selenium in Python to enter text into a search field on the USPS careers website:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="WD40"]"}`

The URL is: https://wp1-ext.usps.gov/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/hrrcf_a_unreg_job_search#

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/NAME/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://wp1-ext.usps.gov/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/hrrcf_a_unreg_job_search#")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("WD40")
elem.send_keys("denver")
```

When I dive into the selectors, the following is in the input field.

```
<input id="WD40" ct="I" lsdata="{29:'WD3E'}" lsevents="{Change:[{ResponseData:'delta',EnqueueCardinality:'single'},{}]}" type="text" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsField__input" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="WD40" style="width:350px;" title="">
```

So I should be able to enter the ID of 'WD40' into the ID field, but I am still getting that error.

Please send help.

Comment: You can try doing `find_element_by_id` but this should work as well. Your code works for me. Perhaps you should upgrade your Python, Selenium or Chrome driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a *dynamic* element so to locate/`click()` on the element using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://wp1-ext.usps.gov/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/hrrcf_a_unreg_job_search#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.lsField__input"))).send_keys("denver")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://wp1-ext.usps.gov/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/hrrcf_a_unreg_job_search#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='lsField__input']"))).send_keys("denver")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: denver]

Comment: Thank you DebanjanB!  This worked quite well.  I had no idea that the element needed to be clicked manually before typing could occur.  
Does this mean that the input technically doesn't exist until I click it?

Comment: @MikeJani Factually, we haven't clicked, but we waited for the `element_to_be_clickable` for the JavaScript/AJAX to complete before invoking `send_keys("denver")`